# Importing custom module into jupyter notebook

Tags: python, import, jupyter-notebook

Yes, I know this is a recurrent question but I still couldn't find a convincing answer. I even read at https://chrisyeh96.github.io/2017/08/08/definitive-guide-python-imports.html but could not find out how to solve the problem:

I'm running python 3.6 project that includes jupyter (ipython) notebooks. I want the notebook to import a custom local `helpers.py` package that I will probably use also later in other sources.

The project structure is similar to:

```
my_project/
│
├── my_project/
│   ├── notebooks/
│       └── a_notebook.ipynb
│   ├── __init__.py     # suppose to make package `my_project` importable
│   └── helpers.py
│
├── tests/
│   └── helpers_tests.py
│
├── .gitignore
├── LICENSE
├── README.md
├── requirements.txt
└── setup.py
```

When importing `helpers` in the notebook I get the error:

```
----> 4 import helpers

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'helpers'
```

I also tried `from my_project import helpers` and I get the same error `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'my_project'`

I finally (and temporarily) used the usual trick:

```
import sys
sys.path.append('..')
import helpers
```

But it looks awful and I'm still looking for a better solution

Comment: Have you tried form .. import helpers or something like that? Try relative imports

Comment: Have you tried moving helpers.py to the notebooks directory?

Comment: Of course I could do that @NielsHenkens and it'll work but I don't like this solution since I want to reuse the functions in `helpers.py` in other part of  my_project, not only in notebooks that are only exploratory phases. helpers are not specific to their use in the notebooks.

Comment: @RaydelMiranda: relative import like the one you suggest returns the error `ValueError: attempted relative import beyond top-level package`. I've also tried `from ..my_project import helpers`

Answer (score 45):

One can tell python where to look for modules via `sys.path`. I have a project structure like this:

```
project/
    │
    ├── src/
    │    └── my_module/
    │        ├── __init__.py       
    │        └── helpers.py
    ├── notebooks/
    │   └── a_notebook.ipynb
    ...
```

I was able to load the module like so:

```py
import sys
sys.path.append('../src/')

from my_module import helpers
```

One should be able load the module from wherever they have it.

Answer (score 3):

Here I could find several solutions. Some of them are similar to the ones answered before:
https://mg.readthedocs.io/importing-local-python-modules-from-jupyter-notebooks/index.html

Comment: It would be better to post one or more of the solutions from the link directly here as an answer. See [Why is linking bad?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7515/why-is-linking-bad) or [Are answers that just contain links elsewhere really “good answers”?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8231/are-answers-that-just-contain-links-elsewhere-really-good-answers)

Answer (score 2):

If you move the `notebooks` directory out one level, and then explicitly import your module from the package, that should do it. So your directory would look like this:

```
my_project/
│
├── my_project/
│   ├── __init__.py       
│   └── helpers.py
├── notebooks/
│   └── a_notebook.ipynb
...
```

and then your import statement within the notebook would be:

`from my_project import helpers`.

Comment: Have you run the `setup.py` file such that the `my_project` package has been installed?

Comment: No, I don't use `setup.py`. Should I?

Comment: Well, the only reason for you to have a `setup.py` file and all the `__init__.py` files in this folder is if you want to use `my_project` like a package. In order to install that package into Python, you would need to run `python setup.py`. 

However, if you don't want to use `my_project` like a package, but rather just as a collection of modules, then there is no need to have `setup.py` or `__init__.py` in this folder. In this case, you would move `a_notebook.ipynb` into the `my_project` folder (next to `helpers.py`) and just do `import helpers` within the notebook.

Comment: @lauren.marietta unfortunately in jupyter notebook you cant import the module as easy just like that even if you put your own module in the same file. the output always showed 'no input name 'blabla' '. this is really hard if you want to do unittest.  otherwise anyone can suggest other IDE that is easier to import own module?

Comment: Tried exactly this example and it did not work for me.

Answer (score 2):

Try the following line:

`from my_project.helpers import what_you_need`

This line should also work:

`import my_project.helpers`

Answer (score 2):

This worked for me.

```py
import sys

MODULE_FULL_PATH = '/<home>/<username>/my_project/my_project'

sys.path.insert(1, MODULE_FULL_PATH)

from my_module import helpers
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you need a `__init__.py` module in the `notebooks/` directory. I haven't really used Jupyter notebooks before so I could be wrong. You may also need to try changing your import statement to:

```
import .. helpers
```

to indicate that the import statement is for a local package that is located in the parent directory of the Jupyter notebook.

Comment: for first suggestion: `__init__.py` enables the directory that contains it to be a package that can be imported. The purpose here is not to make `notebooks` a package to import. 
About relative imports you suggest, the correct syntax is `from .. import helpers`. It gives the error (I've also tried `from ..my_project import helpers`):   
`ValueError: attempted relative import beyond top-level package`

Comment: This is incorrect, in any case, it should be `import ..helpers` for one level up

Comment: This leads to: SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Answer (score 0):

If you are on a Unix/Linux system another elegant solution may be creating a "soft link" to the module file `helpers.py` that you would like to use. Change to the `notebooks` directory and create the link to the module file this way:

`cd notebooks; ln -fs ../my_project/helpers.py .`

This "soft link" is essentially a pointer (a shortcut) to the original target file. With the link in place you will be import your module file as usual:

`import helpers`

Answer (score 0):

It is probably too late for answer, but the solution for me was pretty much simple.
My problem was that I first created a project in Jupiter, and then add e helpers.py with my finctions. So basically your Jupiter notebook won't see it untill you restart the Kernel in your Jupiter Notebook. Make sure you did that, and once you do, your imports strat works no problems.