# Jupyter Notebook: Newly added functions not accessible

Tags: python, function, jupyter-notebook, package, addition

similar to [this issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53049195/importing-custom-module-into-jupyter-notebook) and this [topic related article](https://www.pythoncentral.io/how-to-create-a-python-package/), I have created my own 
package within Jupyter Notebook. I can successfully access module content after the first import of a python file.

However, whenever I'd like to add a new function to the python file, I am unable to access it then within my notebook.

I've tried the following: 
- adjust and save the python file online
- delete the old python version and upload a new one

The only thing working was to upload the python file with a different name. But this is not really what I want to achieve :D

Anyone here having an idea how to add new functions with direct access ability?

This is how I import my modules:

```
import os
import sys
sys.path.insert(0, os.path.abspath('/home/ubuntu/jupyter/src/..'))
from src.parsing import general

general.    <-- function list popping up
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the issue. It was rather obvious. You need to restart the kernel, so that the newly added methods can be accessed.

Just rerunning the import cell is not sufficient.

Answer (score 0):

When you are in a cell with the code/function you want to use, press Shift + Enter to be able to access that code in the next cell.

Comment: Thanks for the hint. This is clear to me.
The issue is that NEW functions added to a python package file don't show up even after new import of the module within a cell.

Comment: Ah I see, one suggestion is to make sure you are modifying a module from the version of python that you are installing. If its source code you are modifying, make sure that you actually install the package via pip.