# How to install or import a repository from GitHub?

Tags: python, github, jupyter-notebook, package, repository

I have never cloned or installed a package from GitHub before.

What I have done so far was installed GitBash and typed,

```
gitclone $ git clone https://github.com/quantumjot/unet_segmentation_metrics.git
```

It showed me the following:

```
Cloning into 'unet_segmentation_metrics'...
remote: Enumerating objects: 98, done.
remote: Counting objects: 100% (98/98), done.
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (68/68), done.
remote: Total 98 (delta 37), reused 88 (delta 27), pack-reused 0
Receiving objects: 100% (98/98), 1.00 MiB | 826.00 KiB/s, done.
Resolving deltas: 100% (37/37), done.
```

but how do I go about installing the package into my jupyter notebook?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Importing custom module into jupyter notebook](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53049195/importing-custom-module-into-jupyter-notebook)

Answer (score 0):

The installation procedure is provided on the GitHub repository.

Comment: i dont really quite get it.

for example, i didnt know i had to install GitBash to clone, and I dont know where to go to write this:


$ cd unet_segmentation_metrics
$ pip install .

Comment: As per the GitHub repository the author has mentioned that after cloning the repository you can traverse into directory where module code is present and just run `pip install .` to add the module.

Comment: open the bash terminal in the cloned directory and just run pip install command